# Calculating variance

Tags: probability

Alice
passes
through
four
traffic
lights
on
her
way
to
work,
and
each
light
is
equally
likely
to
be
green
or
red,
independently
of
the
others.
(a)
What
is
the
PMF,
the
mean,
and
the
variance
of
the
number
of
red
lights
that
Alice
encounters?
(b)
Suppose
that
each
red
light
delays
Alice
by
exactly
two
minutes.
What
is
the
variance
of
Alice’s
commuting
time?

a) X = no of red lights passed. X is binomially distributed with n=4, p=0.5.

Mean = np = 2

Var = np(1-p)=1

PMF = nCk * 0.5^ k * 0.5 ^ (4-k)

Problem lies in b. I thought the variance would be the same as variance of X.

.: Var(time) = 1 * 2 minutes

But the answer was Var(2X) = 2^2*Var(X) =4

Can you explain?

Comment: Since X is the number of red lights passed and each red light delays Alice by 2 minutes, then 2X is the delay time in minutes.

Comment: @StefanHansen this means the answer was Var (2 minutes * X)?

Comment: Yes, $\mathrm{Var}(2X)=2^2\mathrm{Var}(X)$ by properties of the variance.

Answer (score 1):

It's because $Var(aX+b) = a^2 Var(X)$, here your $a=2$.

Comment: Since each traffic light delays the trip by 2 mins, the total delay is $2X$, where $X$ is the number of traffic lights. So the variance of the delay is the variance of $2X$ (NOT $X_1 + X_2$) $Var(2X) = E((2X)^2) - [E(2X)]^2= 4E((X)^2) - [2E(X)]^2 = 4( E((X)^2) - [E(X)]^2)= 4Var(X)$ by the definition of variance.